# duplicate class in ftc android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

So i imported this project in hope that i learn something. I uploaded the code on the robot and the robot worked perfectly fine. Weird thing is, minutes after i uploaded the code the laptop started giving me the 'cannot resolve symbol' error, i solved that and now i have some duplicate class error. I've been stuck at this point for 2 weeks now, i would really really appreciate some help.
The error looks like this:

```
Duplicate class com.google.ftcreasearch.tfod.BuildConfig found in modules jetified-tfod-1.0.2-runtime (orc.firstinspires.ftc:tfod:1.0.2) and jetified-tfod-release-runtime (:tfod-release:)
```

thing is, the code was made a year ago so it had some outdated gradle files, without updating them the program gave me the 'cannot resolve symbol' error on almost every line, as mentioned above. After updating them i get the duplicate class error.
*UPDATE* I manually deleted the duplicates(i saw a video on youtube of a guy going in the files and deleting them so i did the same), i went where the modules were "hidden" and deleted them. As expected another problem has occured

```
2 files found with path 'lib/arm64-v8a/libimage_utils.so' from inputs:
```

- C:\Users\name.gradle\caches\transforms-3\c09d9b3577f163a962e3ae4caf80e495\transformed\jetified-tfod-release\jni\arm64-v8a\libimage_utils.so
- C:\Users\name.gradle\caches\transforms-3\f0d42d80572ccbf9ef09ab02117d3471\transformed\jetified-tfod-1.0.2\jni\arm64-v8a\libimage_utils.so

deleting them would just make another 2 appear, the app gives me a link to a site that recommends removing the "jni" files, i just dont know how to do that.

Comment: i think your dependecy have two version of this class , try to exclude one at yiur build.gradle with you with exclude command .